# Who to hire to attach a weather seal?

Tags: mercedes-benz, seal, classic

I'm a decent shadetree mechanic but I think I've been defeated by a particularly tricky weather seal. I've destroyed two seals trying to put it on myself. What type of specialist should I go to for this kind of work? I was thinking an automotive glass guy or maybe a body shop. Or should I just go to the dealer?

Comment: Where does the seal go? Add a picture if you can

Comment: Why not just tell us exactly what you're doing and what part of the vehicle you're doing it to. We may be able to help you figure out what you're doing wrong so you can finish the job yourself. Just a thought.

Comment: It's the rear seal to a power sunroof on a '79 MB 300CD. I've removed the sunroof from the vehicle and spent a couple afternoons trying to slide the new seal into the groove using soapy water and/or silicone spray as lubricant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@neuromancer, in that case i would call a glass company and ask if the can or refer you to who can do the repair. If you take it to a dealer they will most likely sub the work out to anothercompany anyways.

Comment: My auto-glass guy referred me to a sunroof specialist, who said he could do it.